# How to place two divs next to each other, one of which contains an image that scales according to the size of the other div?

Tags: css, html

I'm learning CSS and HTML as I go along, so excuse my ignorance.

I've been trying to create an about me page for the past few hours trying various combinations of CSS and HTML to get this to work but I'm having some trouble. Essentially, I'm trying to have a body of text next to a vertical image. Im trying to get the image on the right to scale so that it is the same height as the body of text and so that the image is slightly seperated from the div.I'd also like it to fill up the division; the images show what I'm trying to achieve.

This is what I've accomplished:

Progress:

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Here's the relevant code:

```css
.Row {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  /*this was fixed*/
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.Column {
  display: table-cell;
}

.Column #aboutMe {
  background-color: rgba(50, 74, 17, 1.00);
  margin-right: 20%;
  float: left;
}

.Column #aboutMe h1 {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.Column #aboutMe p {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.Column #test {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!--About me start-->

<div class="Row">
  <div class="Column">
    <div id="aboutMe">
      <h1 id="blogTitle">What it's all about</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut porttitor eros justo, ut facilisis nisi faucibus id. Sed venenatis aliquam rutrum. Maecenas id elementum quam, eget molestie sapien. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et
        malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse eu tristique ligula. Mauris a mollis felis. Vivamus finibus mi quam, ac varius quam pretium in. Etiam fermentum dolor commodo massa fermentum, egestas porta ex bibendum. Vestibulum ac erat sem. Nam
        interdum risus et tortor efficitur pretium. Curabitur lobortis massa lectus, non efficitur nisi ornare vel. Proin porttitor commodo libero, quis accumsan dui hendrerit at. Aliquam eget dui placerat, luctus nisi et, auctor mi. Aliquam a convallis
        enim. Donec at nisl nec massa mollis convallis.
      </p>
      <p>
        Curabitur tristique lacus non leo dapibus, at mattis est rutrum. Duis vel porttitor neque, nec aliquam nulla. Donec pulvinar, dui sed blandit ultrices, justo leo cursus turpis, vitae vehicula massa nisl nec erat. Vestibulum tincidunt urna non lorem consequat
        pulvinar. Curabitur dignissim varius odio, eget dignissim lectus feugiat et. Praesent sit amet euismod purus. Sed lobortis bibendum risus, quis iaculis justo fermentum quis. Integer consectetur pellentesque nibh, eu dignissim odio facilisis sodales.
      </p>
      <p>
        Nullam a felis euismod, sollicitudin enim eget, laoreet sapien. Nullam non nulla aliquet, gravida arcu sed, laoreet libero. Quisque hendrerit lobortis hendrerit. Etiam condimentum urna elit, ac tincidunt erat facilisis ut. Nullam semper leo felis, vitae
        dictum dui placerat a. Maecenas ornare, lacus id vestibulum euismod, libero turpis efficitur lectus, ac vehicula odio magna sit amet lacus. Quisque id scelerisque erat. Cras placerat pulvinar libero quis lobortis. Morbi nec sem id risus scelerisque
        molestie. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec condimentum ex ac lectus porttitor, a varius elit semper. Curabitur laoreet sit amet nisl in varius. Duis eu ipsum ac risus consectetur
        porta vitae eget dolor. Sed blandit, leo vitae efficitur auctor, est mi dapibus dui, et iaculis dui odio et neque.
      </p>
      <p>
        Cras libero nibh, ullamcorper sed aliquet euismod, posuere ac erat. Nam eget tincidunt odio. Nam sed justo iaculis, blandit ui non, luctus quam. Fusce nibh ligula, laoreet laoreet eleifend a, convallis ac ex. Aenean interdum elit at erat cursus tincidunt.
        Ut a placerat enim. Sed gravida fermentum varius
      </p>
      <p>
        Curabitur vestibulum feugiat gravida. Phasellus aliquet auctor dictum. Sed sed tristique justo, id facilisis quam. Suspendisse mattis erat dolor, ac convallis sem dapibus eget. Aenean tempus posuere nibh, at molestie ante gravida vel. Praesent at accumsan
        augue. Fusce volutpat et sem nec ullamcorper. Nam massa urna, sodales ac quam vitae, feugiat vulputate metus. Praesent commodo sit amet nibh in rutrum. Aliquam augue nunc, molestie eget consequat et, pretium nec risus. Sed aliquam massa sapien,
        eu suscipit tortor vehicula suscipit. Maecenas et ligula vel metus dignissim vestibulum ac in nulla. Cras id ornare ligula.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Column">
    <img id="test" src="images/about.jpg">
  </div>

</div>
<!--About me end-->
```

I'd really appreciate help on getting this fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the problem you describe, I think I would try to go with the grid approach. Making use of this rather recent CSS feature would make it easier for you to have a responsive page while having rather small boilerplate CSS to start with.
You can read more there https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp or probably easily find tutorials about the CSS grid.

For your specific problem, here is a small snippet I came up with:

```css
.Row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 8fr 2fr;
  grid-template-areas: "content picture";
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
}

.Column {
  grid-area: content;
}

.Column #aboutMe {
  background-color: rgba(50, 74, 17, 1.00);
  float: left;
}

.Column #aboutMe h1 {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.Column #aboutMe p {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.Picture-Container {
  grid-area: picture;
}

.Picture {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Row">
  <div class="Column">
    <div id="aboutMe">
      <h1 id="blogTitle">What it's all about</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut porttitor eros justo, ut facilisis nisi faucibus id. Sed venenatis aliquam rutrum. Maecenas id elementum quam, eget molestie sapien. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et
        malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse eu tristique ligula. Mauris a mollis felis. Vivamus finibus mi quam, ac varius quam pretium in. Etiam fermentum dolor commodo massa fermentum, egestas porta ex bibendum. Vestibulum ac erat sem. Nam
        interdum risus et tortor efficitur pretium. Curabitur lobortis massa lectus, non efficitur nisi ornare vel. Proin porttitor commodo libero, quis accumsan dui hendrerit at. Aliquam eget dui placerat, luctus nisi et, auctor mi. Aliquam a convallis
        enim. Donec at nisl nec massa mollis convallis.
      </p>
      <p>
        Curabitur tristique lacus non leo dapibus, at mattis est rutrum. Duis vel porttitor neque, nec aliquam nulla. Donec pulvinar, dui sed blandit ultrices, justo leo cursus turpis, vitae vehicula massa nisl nec erat. Vestibulum tincidunt urna non lorem consequat
        pulvinar. Curabitur dignissim varius odio, eget dignissim lectus feugiat et. Praesent sit amet euismod purus. Sed lobortis bibendum risus, quis iaculis justo fermentum quis. Integer consectetur pellentesque nibh, eu dignissim odio facilisis sodales.
      </p>
      <p>
        Nullam a felis euismod, sollicitudin enim eget, laoreet sapien. Nullam non nulla aliquet, gravida arcu sed, laoreet libero. Quisque hendrerit lobortis hendrerit. Etiam condimentum urna elit, ac tincidunt erat facilisis ut. Nullam semper leo felis, vitae
        dictum dui placerat a. Maecenas ornare, lacus id vestibulum euismod, libero turpis efficitur lectus, ac vehicula odio magna sit amet lacus. Quisque id scelerisque erat. Cras placerat pulvinar libero quis lobortis. Morbi nec sem id risus scelerisque
        molestie. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec condimentum ex ac lectus porttitor, a varius elit semper. Curabitur laoreet sit amet nisl in varius. Duis eu ipsum ac risus consectetur
        porta vitae eget dolor. Sed blandit, leo vitae efficitur auctor, est mi dapibus dui, et iaculis dui odio et neque.
      </p>
      <p>
        Cras libero nibh, ullamcorper sed aliquet euismod, posuere ac erat. Nam eget tincidunt odio. Nam sed justo iaculis, blandit ui non, luctus quam. Fusce nibh ligula, laoreet laoreet eleifend a, convallis ac ex. Aenean interdum elit at erat cursus tincidunt.
        Ut a placerat enim. Sed gravida fermentum varius
      </p>
      <p>
        Curabitur vestibulum feugiat gravida. Phasellus aliquet auctor dictum. Sed sed tristique justo, id facilisis quam. Suspendisse mattis erat dolor, ac convallis sem dapibus eget. Aenean tempus posuere nibh, at molestie ante gravida vel. Praesent at accumsan
        augue. Fusce volutpat et sem nec ullamcorper. Nam massa urna, sodales ac quam vitae, feugiat vulputate metus. Praesent commodo sit amet nibh in rutrum. Aliquam augue nunc, molestie eget consequat et, pretium nec risus. Sed aliquam massa sapien,
        eu suscipit tortor vehicula suscipit. Maecenas et ligula vel metus dignissim vestibulum ac in nulla. Cras id ornare ligula.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Picture-Container">
    <img class="Picture" src="images/about.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

One potential issue though with this approach overall (yours or mine) is that it seems unlikely your picture will look nice given the width or height of it will depend on the screen where the page is displayed.